# Adding the Values in One Range of Cells to the end of the Formulas in Another Range of Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I am using Excel 2010.

Cells A1:A100 contain numeric values.

Cells A101:A200 contain numeric-valued formulas.

How can I easily add the value in A1 to the end of the formula for A101, do the same for A2 / A102, and so on up to A100 / A200?

EXAMPLE
Before:
A1 contains 50
A101 contains =14+25+100

After:
A101 contains = 14+25+100+50

And so on for A2 / A102 up to A100 / A200...

It is far too tedious and error prone to do this manually (and I have to do this every month!), so I'd like to find a non-manual way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Excel`:

- Copy `A1:A100` to the keyboard.
- Place the cursor to `A101`.
- Right click, `Paste Special-->Operation-->Add`.

`VBA`:

```
Sub copy_and_add()
    Range("A1:A100").Copy
    Range("A101").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
End Sub
```

I hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I've got an idea but not sure how you're file is structured so sorry if it's not useful.

In cell B101, I would put in a formula that is `=A101+A1`
Drag that down for as many entries you need for the month (e.g. A101 - A200) and then just copy and paste special as values from B101-B200 over A101-A200.

You would lose the calculation in those formulas though.

Answer (score 0):

What if cell A1 contains numeric value and cell B1 contains text and I want them both in C1?
Ex:
A1=200
B1=C
Then C1 should be 200C

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
=sum (A1:A200)
```

if youu want too add all the numbers filled in `a1` to `a200` field.
hope its helpfull.